# WifiManager.getScanResults() not giving SSID on Android Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am trying to get results of the latest access point scan. so using this method as provided in Android documentation [WifiManager in Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults())

In other all devices and versions , It works fine, Just giving problem on Android Jelly Bean.
It doesn't give the SSID name in the results retrieved from this method.

I have read in many places that there is a problem of double quotes " " in the Jelly Bean , and yes it is true, because I have checked the currently connected wifi name and it was enclosed in " ", so I only removed the starting and ending quotes and it give me good name.
But while getting the results from WifiManger.getScanResults(), It is not even giving the SSID name in the retrieved result.

Here is the code

```
    wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false) { // If Wifi is off, Switch it on
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }

    receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    wifi.startScan();
    results = wifi.getScanResults();

    for(int i=0 ; i<results.size(); i++){       
        String reslt = results.get(i).toString();   
        Log.d("TAG", "wifi ->>>" + reslt);
    }
```

Can anyone help me in this problem ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you please show the code what you have done.

Comment: updated the question. Added the code in question. @pavanmvn

Answer (score 0):

THe Pre Android Version enclosed the SSID in quotes While post Jelly Bean doesnot
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getSSID()

Answer (score 0):

I have found the alternative method for this I am pasting the code below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WifiManager mWifiManager;
String Available_Networks="";
TextView ShowSSIDs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    //mWifiManager.startScan();
    ShowSSIDs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ssId);
    List<WifiConfiguration> mScanResults = mWifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for(int x=0; x<mScanResults.size();x++){
        Available_Networks+=mScanResults.get(x).SSID+"\n";
    }
    ShowSSIDs.setText(Available_Networks);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}